# need a single line return from mysql

Tags: php, html, mysql

i am developing a php websites where i need to show the result from sql server data.Currently the main problem is that when i my code fetch the data from sql server 2014  it will break down the string in to new line.But i want to show it in a single line.Like name Nijar Hosssain.

[image]

My code is here for fetching the data from sql server 2014

```
<tr>
<td><div align="center"><?php echo $result["Name"];?></div></td>
<td><?php echo $result["Fathersname"];?></td>
<td><?php echo $result["mothersname"];?></td>
<td><div align="center"><?php echo $result["Presentaddress"];?></div></td>
<td align="right"><?php echo $result["peraddress"];?></td>
<td align="right"><?php echo $result["bloodgroup"];?></td>
<td align="right"><?php echo $result["email"];?></td>
<td align="right"><?php echo $result["nationalid_passportno"];?></td>
<td align="right"><?php echo $result["gender"];?></td>
<td align="center"><a href="edit.php?applicant_id=<?php echo $result["applicant_id"];?>">Edit</a></td>
```

Comment: Not only increase the size of HTML column using CSS?

Comment: if `name` is not having any new line character in DB then it is design issue not a `php` or `mysql`. Use `nowrap` like `<td nowrap><?php echo $result["Name"];?></td>`

Answer (score 0):

This is not mysql problem. You just need to increate 'Name' column width in css. This displays full name like Nijar Hosssain in single line.

```
<td class="name"><div align="center"><?php echo $result["Name"];?></div></td>
```

In css you can write

```
.name { width:10%; }
```

Comment: While your answer appears to be correct, it would benefit from a bit more detail, preferably a bit of example code, since the asker is obviously very new to the subject.